# how to get or extract inofrmation from an object in C#?

Tags: c#

i used an interface class and make an object from that class (having method with return type void). now that object has too many information and i want to get only some required information .

interface:

```
public interface Iclass
{
    void OnEventReceived(event ev);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please specify what you expect as a result in oppose to your current result.

Comment: i want technique in coding language to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

> now that object has too many information and i want to get only some required information

This means that your design is wrong. You have polluted the interface with some un-necessary methods/or methods that should have been a part of some other interface. You should re-consider your design and breaking the interface to multiple interfaces. So that your classes implement only the required interface.

Comment: there is some information which is required for later use . and there is some information which needed to be get extracted

Comment: @user3176222 explain the question completely then. Unless your scenario is clear you won't get a answer that you might be after.